# PayPal Express without SSL

Tags: paypal, nopcommerce

I'm using NopCommerce 3.0 system with PayPal Express plugin (http://noppaypalexpress.codeplex.com/). It used to work without HTTPS, but not it doesn't. I know that in Magento there is an option called "Transfer Shipping Options", after disabling it PayPal doesn't require SSL. Can anyone explain me what does this option actually do? What does it set in the PayPal API? I could not find anything in the PayPal documentation or in the plugin source code. Unfortunately installing SSL certificate is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transfer shipping options uses a CALLBACKURL, which must be HTTPS.  I don't have specific knowledge of NopCommerce, but most likely they haven't even implemented this functionality.

Express Checkout w/o a CALLBACK should work fine from an HTTP site, with a RETURNURL/CANCELURL that also happens to be HTTP.  It is up to the cart module to pass the correct URL to PayPal so the buyer may return to the site and complete the checkout.